# What is the chance of Mehrune's Razor to proc?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently obtained the Mehrune's Razor dagger. The enchantment is "Hits have a small chance to instantly kill". What are the chances of the effect working?

[image]

Comment: I have no data for this, but I think "a chance" is 10% and "a small chance" is 5% or 1%, and a "good chance" is 20%

Comment: After like 30 hours of playing with this dagger, it did not loose any charges.

Comment: @GMNoob certainly no more than 5% chance.  I've been using this dagger for a long time and if it was more than 5% chance I'd definitely notice.  Ordag, this dagger, even when it procs, seems to lose no charges.

Comment: @yx. Ah, that could be possible, never noticed its ability though.

Comment: @ordag I notice the ability a lot when I'm fighting high HP enemies like druegar overlords and ancient dragons.  Its always a nice surprise when they suddenly drop dead with a near full health bar.

Comment: According to http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Mehrunes%27_Razor_%28Skyrim%29 quotes the prima guide stating it puts the chance at 1%. That piece of information has not been confirmed and is seen as unreliable, though.

Comment: sounds to me like I need to go test this later today!  I smell more science ahead

Comment: i have had it for a while, i might have seen it just proc once. better to get a daedric dagger with a double frost/shock enchant :)

Comment: If you want to change the instant-kill chance of the Mehrunes Razor, use one of these mods: [Mehrunes Razor Higher Kill Chance](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=10186) or [Mehrunes Razor -Improved-](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=13232).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Testing can be awfully bloody sometimes.  Just ask Constance Michel:

[image: For Science!]

So I went around in god mode with the Mehrune's Razor and tested it on a bunch of NPCs after doing the following:

1. Disable their AI via tai
2. Set their health to 5000 via setav health 5000 (so they don't die to regular damage)
3. Go on a rampage spree in Riften

Here are the # of hits before dying:

- 15
- 14
- 1 (Super unlucky guard)
- 114 (Super lucky guard)
- 39
- 3
- 36
- 51
- 21
- 46
- 67
- 28
- 66
- 66
- 19
- 70
- 22
- 76
- 34
- 18
- 29
- 36
- 61
- 47
  Average: 38.8333333 hits (stdev 26.8, which is quite high...)

This works out to be ~2.57% +/-1.78% margin of error

If anyone wants to provide more sample points, go right ahead.  For now, I'm going to conclude that the chance to proc is roughly 2.5%

Comment: One final thing, the dagger will not proc against any essential NPCs

Comment: +1 for serving Lord Dagon. [Greet the new day, Brother.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Mythic_Dawn#Joining_the_Faction)

Comment: No that can't be right. This is my favorite weapon. It always works.

Comment: @user19403 I'm sure it'll work eventually, if you keep stabbing.

Comment: @user19403 With the mods, [*Mehrunes Razor Higher Kill Chance*](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/10186) or [*Mehrunes Razor -Improved-*](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/13232), you can make it *always* work.

Answer (score 9):

yx. might need to check his math. I get a mean of 40.7917 for the values he quoted, with a standard deviation of 26.8.

This means 955 hits were non-instant while 24 were instant-kill hits.

Combining this with my own data of roughly 849 hits with 31 instant-kills (plus a few more) gives a total of 1955 regular hits & 58 instant-kill hits.

I applied a Bayesian approach and set the prior density to a half-triangle that peaks at zero, since most people assumed it was small. The final result is:

(2.91 +- 0.74)%,

where the +- indicates a 95% probability interval. As a hunch, since game programmers might prefer round numbers, our data together suggests that 3% might be the true proc rate.

Comment: its a possibility, we won't know for sure until the CS comes out.  You are right though, average should be 40.7917 instead of 38.8, but 2.5% or 3% both falls within the error margin.

Comment: You people scare me, like really scare me.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [UESP Mehrunes' Razor article](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mehrunes%27_Razor), the chance of the Mehrunes' Razor instant kill effect activating is **2/101** or ~ **1.98%**.

Note: This is the *actual* chance of activating, as this information was extracted from the game's files using the [Creation Kit](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Creation_Kit).

Comment: If you feel that the instant kill chance of Mehrunes' Razor is too small, try the mods **[Mehrunes Razor Higher Kill Chance](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=10186)** or **[Mehrunes Razor -Improved-](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=13232)** to increase the chances of the instant kill effect activating.

Comment: "They've done studies, you know. 60% of the time, it works every time."